# how to reveal function names that are bound to mouse buttons (eg <down-mouse-1>)?

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

Emacs buttonizes specific expression in the buffers. For example, email ids, urls attachments in gnus buffer, and [back], [forward] in help buffers and so on. When we click on those with mouse, they act appropriately.

How to know which function is called when clicking (with mouse) on such a buttons?

`C-h k` isn't of much help here.

**Edit:** this question is already answered. The reason I wanted to know is to bind keys like firefox to go back and forth in the history of help buffer.

Now I have the following in my `.emacs`

```
(define-key help-mode-map (kbd "M-<left>") 'help-go-back)
(define-key help-mode-map (kbd "M-<right>") 'help-go-forward)
```

Comment: _“C-h k isn't of much help here.”_ It works for me in the help buffer links. What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: emacs trunk, `C-h k` just tells me that it is bound to `mouse-drag-region` which is not much revealing about the final function which acted on with the mouse click

Comment: `C-h k` should tell you **both** that `down-mouse-1` is bound to `mouse-drag-region` **and** that `mouse-1` is bound to `mouse-set-point`. A mouse click involves both a down event and an up event. The "*final function which acted on with the mouse click*" is the function bound to the up event.

Comment: @Drew I wonder how to trace double click. Which seems to be different function as single one, am I right?

Comment: @DimaFomin: See `mouse.el` - look for `event-click-count`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can view a considerable amount of information about buttons (and other text properties and overlays) by placing point on them and using `what-cursor-position` with a prefix arg, that is, `C-u C-x =`. The help page this brings up has links describing the button information.

As an example, take the `[back]` buttons in `*Help*`. `C-u C-x =` with point on that button brings up an help page listing various text properties: click on the link next to `category` and you should see something like this:

```
Category help-back-button:

  action               help-button-action
  evaporate            t
  face                 button
  follow-link          t
  help-echo            [Show]
  help-function        help-xref-go-back
  keymap               [Show]
  mouse-face           highlight
  rear-nonsticky       t
  supertype            help-xref
  type                 help-back

[back]
```

You can see that the action function is `help-button-action` (which as it happens will look at some of the other properties here to decide what to do).

(Note that this all has more to do with *buttons* than the mouse itself. Using the keyboard will fire the same function.)

Comment: Thanks, I expected it to be something to do with overlay. had no clue how to look into overlays.